# Операция остатка от деления

Tags: числа, деление

3 / 5 = 3 
(-3) / 5 = -3
Если мы 3 делим 5 то получаем 0,6. Откуда берется остаток 3?

Я это взял [отсюда](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2193/67/lecture/1962) и подумал, что может я чего-то не знаю, потому что 500 человек окончило этот курс и никто не заметил, не написал об ошибке.

А как так получается, что google на запрос 3 / 5 выдает результат 3?

Comment: Восхитительно, в алгебре появилось новое направление. Если мы делим три на пять, то нацело делится ноль, а остаток - три.

Comment: остаток существует только при целочисленном делении. 0.6 получится при вещественном делении.

Вообще то, остатки при делении изучают в классе 3. А вещественное деление в классе 5. Что то тут неувязочка:)

Comment: @DreamChild, зато теперь он научится!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция целочисленного деления может быть формально описана таким языком:

A / B = C, С -- это такое максимальное число, которое будет удовлетворять выражению

C * B <= A. В случае если либо A, либо B отрицательное. то знак минус выносится за скобки, выполняется поиск числа C и затем минус приписывается найденному числу C.

Остаток от деления это:

A / B = C + K, где A, B, C числа как и в целочисленном делении, только K -- это такое число, которое удовлетворяет равенству C * B + K = A; если C, A и B известны, то K можно найти сразу K = A - C * B

Пример с 3 и 5:

Перебираем ( для примера )

- 3 / 5 = 0 ; Проверяем 0 * 5 = 0; 0 <= 3 (верно) -- подходит
- 3 / 5 = 1 ; Проверяем 1 * 5 = 5; 5 <= 3 (не верно) -- не подходит

Значит ответ 0.

Найдем остаток:

Числа A, B и C нам известны. Найдем остаток K = A - C * B = 3 - 0 = 3;

Писал специально для объяснения принципа.

Answer (score 0):

На википедии [статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%E5%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5_%F1_%EE%F1%F2%E0%F2%EA%EE%EC) есть. Ознакомьтесь с ней, там, в принципе, все понятно написано.